# Is this question a copy?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, exact-duplicates

Looking at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/182800/explain-how-the-internet-works-to-a-complete-computer-novice) question, I recognise both of the two large images in the top two answers - I'm *sure* I've seen both on a Stack Exchange question *somewhere* (I suspect *not* SU), but for the life of me cannot find it.

The user who posted the question *also* posted both answers, and is clearly making a lot of rep out of the question. I'm slightly worried that ***if*** this is a copy question, the user is cheating the system with plagiarised content.

I've not placed this a comment on the question due to my lack of evidence, and the potential for me to have just imagined it, but the more I look at the two images the more I convince myself they're not new to SE.

So thought I'd raise it for the wider audience to see if anyone else recognises them or if I am simply going mad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this question has almost had 24hrs and since no-one else seems to also recognise them, I shall assume that I've imagined seeing these elsewhere on SE and not worry.

Unless someone jumps in with something today I'll tick this post off tomorrow so this question can be discarded.

Thanks to BloodPhilia for some valid points regarding attribution as well.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where they came from and I think you're right that people should credit sources where due, yet there is no no rule on the SE frame that states you have to credit source.

Although of course it is not much appreciated and against the law if the work is under license that requires crediting, until one can acquire proof of such a thing (e.g. the original source or a comment by the original author) no measures can be taken.

If you do find the source it originated from, don't be shy to post credit in a comment to those answers and address the author of the answer about his/her inappropriate behaviour.